# Who is Dr Moreau's nephew?

Tags: comics, league-of-extraordinary-gentlemen

In the League of Extraordinary Gentlemen, vol 2, Murray and Quartermain meet Dr Moreau in a wood in England.  Upon their farewell, he references his nephew visiting him occasionally who paints images of his mutants.  The nephew's name is Gustave.

Given the nature of LXG and its references, I assume Gustave is a reference, but to whom?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jess Nevins has written [annotations for League of Extraordinary Gentlemen](http://www.enjolrasworld.com/Jess%20Nevins/League%20of%20Extraordinary%20Gentlemen/LoEG%20index.htm) where he explains that it is reference to French Symbolist painter Gustave Moreau in [annotations for League of Extraordinary Gentleman vol. 2, issue 6](http://www.enjolrasworld.com/Jess%20Nevins/League%20of%20Extraordinary%20Gentlemen%202/Notes%20on%20League%20of%20Extraordinary%20Gentlemen%20V2%206.html).